# Why do I get, ValueError: two properties with same name when I try to access .ply files using plyfile API?

Tags: python, numpy, point-clouds, valueerror, ply-file-format

I am working with a project that requires accessing point cloud data in the form of .ply files and converting them into numpy arrays for running a deep learning algorithm. When I try to access my .ply files from my directory, I get the error ***"ValueError: two properties with same name"***

The following is my code -

```
import glob
import numpy as np
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement
arr = np.array([])

for filepath in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/PLY Files/*.ply'):
  plyFile = PlyData.read(filepath)
  plyFile.elements[0].properties
```

The following is the error (only relevant portions reproduced here) -

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-4464816991de> in <module>()
      4 
      5 for filepath in glob.iglob('/content/drive/My Drive/PLY Files/*.ply'):
----> 6   plyFile = PlyData.read(filepath)
      7   plyFile.elements[0].properties

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/plyfile.py in _index(self)
    549                                      for prop in self._properties)
    550         if len(self._property_lookup) != len(self._properties):
--> 551             raise ValueError("two properties with same name")
    552 
    553     def ply_property(self, name):

ValueError: two properties with same name
```

My ply file - vertices are partially reproduced (generated by pcl using [pcl_pcd2ply](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/pcl_pcd2ply.1.html) command) :

```
ply
format ascii 1.0
comment PCL generated
element vertex 92928
property float x
property float y
property float z
property list uint uchar _
property float intensity
property list uint uchar _
element camera 1
property float view_px
property float view_py
property float view_pz
property float x_axisx
property float x_axisy
property float x_axisz
property float y_axisx
property float y_axisy
property float y_axisz
property float z_axisx
property float z_axisy
property float z_axisz
property float focal
property float scalex
property float scaley
property float centerx
property float centery
property int viewportx
property int viewporty
property float k1
property float k2
end_header
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 4 0 0 128 63 0 12 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: You'll have to provide the faulty *.ply* file as well. Most likely it's incorrect.

Comment: @CristiFati I have added my ply file to the description. This file was generated by the pcl itself using the pcl_pcd2ply command.

Comment: There you go: `property list uint uchar _` is present twice.

Comment: This file was generated by the pcl command itself. This now makes me wonder if pcl has trouble exporting pcd files to ply files ? Do you suggest I should delete any one of the duplicate values ? Are there any better ways to get correct ply exports than the pcl ?

Comment: I have no idea what *.ply* files are, how are they created, handled, .....

Answer (score 0):

To restate the discussion in the comments on the question, the PLY file in question contains two properties named `_`, which is not supported by `plyfile`.  Unfortunately, I'm not at all familiar with `pcl_pcd2ply`, so I don't know what makes it do this, but it sure seems like a bug somewhere.

Here's a pretty hacky workaround to preprocess ASCII-format PLY files, assuming `property list uint uchar _` is the only duplicated property that can appear.  It will rename the occurrences to `_1`, `_2`, etc.

```
awk '/^property list uint uchar _$/ {x++; $5 = $5 x} BEGIN {x = 0} // {print}' < X.ply
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CristiFati for pointing me to the unusual `property list uint uchar _` which was present twice in the `.ply` file. Supposedly, this kind of parameter was not supposed to be present in a valid `.ply` file. The `_` had to represent some valid property with a unique identifier name. Unfortunately this is a problem in the pcl library.

I did a small workaround to overcome this. It is as follows :

1. The problem is with the direct conversion from `binary` `.pcd` to `ascii` `.ply`
2. The problem was overcome by doing an indirect conversion first from `binary` `.pcd` to `ascii` `.pcd`; and then a second step of conversion from `ascii` `.pcd` to `ascii` `.ply` format. This approach gave a proper `.ply` file without any missing properties.